# Probability of picking bad egg on given day?

Tags: probability

> I have a basket with n eggs. Each day, I eat an egg at random from the basket and then I put a fresh on. After a time T spent in the basket an egg goes bad. What is the probability I pick a bad egg a given day? What is the probability I pick bad eggs two days in a row?

**My attempts:** Any egg that has been in the basket for T days goes bad, at least that is my interpretation. My initial approach was to pick a couple of values for T and n, and work out what happens, but it gets unruly pretty quickly. I'm wondering if there is a better method using maybe first step analysis, or even markov chains that I'm missing that could be used to solve this...

Comment: Are we assuming that after T days, one good egg goes bad, or that any egg that has been in the basket for T days goes bad?

Comment: Any egg that has been in the basket for T days goes bad, at least that is my interpretation. My initial approach was to pick a couple of values for T and n, and work out what happens, but it gets unruly pretty quickly. I'm wondering if there is a better method using maybe first step analysis, or even markov chains that I'm missing that could be used to solve this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you have a fancy egg basket that has labelled slots for the eggs. (Never mind that you could use the labelled slots to keep track of your eggs to keep them from going bad.) When you pick an egg and eat it, you put the replacement in the same labelled slot. That makes it a bit easier to think about this.

The probability that the egg you pick is at least $T$  days old is the probability that you haven’t picked the slot in which it’s sitting for $T$ days, which is $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^T$.

The probability that you pick bad eggs two days in a row is the probablity $1-\frac1n$ that you pick a different slot on the second day, times the probability $\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{T-1}$ that neither of these two slots had been picked for $T-1$ days, times the probablity $1-\frac1n$ that the one you pick on the first day hadn’t been picked the day before those $T-1$ days, for a total probability of $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^2\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{T-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the argument for $(1-\frac{1}{n})^T$ for any day, but for two days in a row, I'm a bit confused. So basically you are saying you are looking for the probability that the egg from the slot you pick second didn't get picked first and vice-versa AND the probability both slots haven't been picked in T-1 days, where T-1 days is because you already take into account the different slots not being picked on the extra day via $(1-\frac{1}{n})^2$?

Could this also be approached by $(1-\frac{1}{n})^T(1-\frac{1}{n-1})^T$, or this is completely incorrect?

Comment: @Shaun: It's incorrect – I'm not sure whether I'd call it "completely incorrect" :-), since it's a good approximation for $n\gg1$. What you have is $\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^T\left(\frac{n-2}{n-1}\right)^T=\left(1-\frac2n\right)^T$, so you're replacing the factor $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^2$ by $1-\frac2n$. That's correct to first order in $\frac1n$, but you're missing the term $\frac1{n^2}$. The difference is perhaps easiest to see for $n=2$ and $T=1$, where your expression is $0$, whereas mine gives the correct result $\frac14$.

Comment: I see, thanks. Yeah I need to get better at conceptualising these problems, I understand the solutions but always find the intuition difficult to begin with. Do you have any courses/texts/etc you could recommend I look at to get better intuition?

Comment: @Shaun: I don't, unfortunately. My formal education was a few decades ago; most of what I know I learned from math.SE, Wikipedia and the like.

Comment: Fair enough, looks like it'll be similar for me :D Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Same result as @joriki by a different approach.  Let's write:
$$P( {\rm egg_1}>T\cap{\rm egg_2}>T)=P( {\rm egg_2}>T|{\rm egg_1}>T)P({\rm egg_1}>T)$$ so that we can recycle @joriki's first result, $P({\rm egg_1}>T)=(1-1/n)^T$. Then, we just need to find $P( {\rm egg_2}>T|{\rm egg_1}>T)$.  Hopefully the notation is clear: $P( {\rm egg}_i>T)$ is the probability that the $i$-th egg we choose is greater than $T$ days old.

Assume $T\ge 1$. Then, in order to both choose a second bad egg and satisfy the ${\rm egg_1}>T$ conditioning criteria, we have to do the following:

1. The $T-1$ draws preceding ${\rm egg}_1$ can only be taken from the $n-1$ distinct slots not corresponding to ${\rm egg}_1$, by the conditioning criteria.  From these, the draws must also not choose the ${\rm egg}_2$ slot, so the probability for this process is $\left(\frac{n-2}{n-1}\right)^{T-1}$.
2. The final ${\rm egg}_2$ draw must correspond to a slot other than the ${\rm egg}_1$ slot, for which we have probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$.

Combining, this gives $$P( {\rm egg_2}>T|{\rm egg_1}>T)=\frac{n-1}{n}\times \left(\frac{n-2}{n-1}\right)^{T-1}=(1-1/n)^{2-T}\times (1-2/n)^{T-1}$$
or, all together:

$$P( {\rm egg_1}>T\cap{\rm egg_2}>T)=(1-2/n)^{T-1}(1-1/n)^{2}$$